# TypeError Unit Test Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I need some help, I'm making some progress towards actually reading through a whole file, however, I've hit a decently sized roadblock (for me it's decent, I'm new to it). I'm trying to mock up most of a controller and I run into a problem when I get about half way through reading the file and I have no idea how to overcome it. I'll include as much code as I can below.

LocationController.js

```
angular
.module('TDE')
.controller('LocationController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$window', '$document', 'LocationService', 'HeaderFooterService', 'SearchService', 'TranslationService', 'MTDE_CONFIG', 'LocationPartnerAssignmentService', 'ExperimentService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $window, $document, $LocationService, $HeaderFooterService, $SearchService, $TranslationService, $MTDE_CONFIG, $LocationPartnerAssignmentService, $ExperimentService) {
//passes over this code

$scope.init = function () {
    // load dropdown for crop list

    // load dropdown for business partner list

    //load dropdown for experimenttype

    //load dropdown for IrrigationType
    //load dropdown for previousCrop

    var locationId = $SearchService.GetLocationId();
    $scope.LocationId=locationId;
    var experimentId = $SearchService.GetExperimentId();
    var experimentPartnerAssignmentId = $SearchService.GetExperimentPartnerAssignmentId();

    //load nitrogen value

    $ExperimentService.GetCrop(onSuccessCropCode,cropId);

    // get location detail from database
    if (locationId === "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
        // Load the Unassigned Location here
        $scope.IsAssinged = false;
    }
    else {
        $LocationService.Detail(onSuccessDetail, locationId);
    }

    // get growing year list
    $scope.GrowingYearList = $LocationService.GrowingYearList();
}

$scope.init(); //I NEED TO BE MOCKED SOMEHOW
```

Helper.js

```
ddescribe("Phases of Testing: The Journey", function () {

describe("Phase I: Test that Jasmine runs", function () {
    it("should test Jasmine is up", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});

describe("Phase II: Try something", function () {
    var DBMock, SyncMock, baseMock, configMock, TransMock, loginMock, locMock, headerMock,
            searchMock, LPAMock, expMock, mockScope, $location, $scope, ctrl, initMock;
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('TDE');
        inject(function (_$location_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
            $location = _$location_;
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            ctrl = _$controller_('LocationController', {
                '$scope': $scope
            });
        });
    });
    it("should be able to grab something", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        expect($scope).toBeDefined();
        expect($scope.PlantingDateNull()).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT:
Now the problem comes down to mocking the $scope.init() function call after it is initially defined. I can't find a good source for help on this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Application:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, environment) {
    $scope.testValue = 'test environment';

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.testValue = 'development environment';
    };

    environment.development && $scope.init();
});

myApp.factory('environment', function() {
    return {
        development: true
    }
});
```

The most important line is `environment.development && $scope.init();`

`environment.development`:

- if it is evaluated to **TRUE** – `$scope.inint()` will be called
- evaluated to **FALSE** – will prevent for calling `$scope.inint()`

To prove it I’m going to stub this servis with two values

**Test:**

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp');
});

beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('environment', mockEnvironment);
    });
});

describe('MyCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controllerInstantiate = $controller;
    }));

    it('prevents call .init() on test environment', function () {
        mockEnvironment.development = false;
        createController();
        expect(scope.testValue).toBe('test environment');
    });

    it('calls init on development environment', function () {
        mockEnvironment.development = true;
        createController();
        expect(scope.testValue).toBe('development environment');
    });

    function createController() {
        return controllerInstantiate('MyCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/2LUp3/

Comment: I really appreciate the help, Krzysztof! I'm just trying to clear through that error honestly. I've been including all the files in the jasmine html file that loads up the webpage. Testing pre-written code is really tough, you've got that right. All I need to do right now is just get it working, that's my current project. It works if that problem line is gone (which is close).

Comment: What error you have? I think that `$SearchService.GetLocationId` returns **cannot call GetLocationId on undefined** as you heven't stub $SearchService for tests

Comment: You can ignore the service calls, those are all loading up, I've got those coming in from when the html page loads, I'm sorry I can't really post extremely helpful code, since it's not exactly my code, it's the groups code. Do you know how I could just ignore one line or mock one line? It just hates the .init() part of $scope. Again, I'm sorry I can't be more helpful

Comment: You can't mock from controller that are called on instantation, if controller is setuped in test it is too late for mock methods like init().
If you run methods like `.init()` inside controllers it smells like that you don't use resolve object on `$routeProvide`. In other words - controller has to much responsibility.

Comment: Oh the joys! Thanks for the help again. I'll do some more digging, because yes, that function is a roadblock, without it I can move, with it I'm stuck. Thanks for all the help, Krzysztof!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide mock for **$LocationService** instead of **LocationService** and create spy for Strips method, something like:

```
describe('myApp', function () {
var scope,
controller,
$mockLocationService = {};

beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp');
});

beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('$LocationService', $mockLocationService);
    });
});

describe('MyCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        $mockLocationService.Strips = jasmine.createSpy('$LocationService.Strips');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    }));

    it('calls Strips method', function () {
        expect($mockLocationService.Strips).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

});

Answer is not anymore related to edited question, sorry.

Comment: That doesn't work, it still gives me the same error as above. Also how do you propose I do a mock for $LocationService, I tried to change it but I need the line $provide.value('LocationService', lockMock); or else the program will crash with it needs that provider.

Comment: Any comments from your side after version change to Jasmine 1.3?

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long to get back to you! I've recently updated to 2.0 like the above mentioned. I've cleared through the strips error but now I've got one issue, that's holding up the show that's different. I'll edit the post above and maybe you'll have an idea. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: If you could get that I would be ecstatic! It dies on that one line that's marked with the big comment. Something about  " at new <anonymous> (file:LocationController.js:207:12)"  *that 207:12 is the line marked!*

Comment: I have answered to your question - if there is no problem - please review it and add some reputation point.
Editing question after correct answer is wasting my time.
I'm open to answer to new your questions according to change to Jasmine 2.0